# BigBlueButton audio and video permission denied

Tags: laravel, nginx, permissions, bigbluebutton

I am using BBB in my Laravel web application for online audio/video calls and conferencing, previously it was working fine but now it is showing audio/video permission denied or not allowed, although I allowed mic and video in chrome but didn't work out.

[image: Mic permission issue]
[image: Webcam permission not allowed]

Note: it is without any error running on IE browser.

Comment: Where you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 10 just go to **Settings** -> search **Microphone privacy settings**. There you have 3 chapters:

- Allow access to the microphone on this device
- Allow apps to access your microphone.
- Allow desktop apps to access your microphone.

You can allow all of them or try some combination which works just to not allow permissions for apps you are not using. Cheers!